# single quote styles are being removed from inline style of rich html

Tags: html, remote-action, richtextarea

When I'm trying to save the html (like below) it is removing the font-family which has quotes, if I do without quotes it works fine but we need quotes for that font family (the color style is un-touched)

Input:

```
<div style='font-family: "Ravi Prakash"; color: #ff0000;'>
This is the Heading
</div>
```

Saved:

```
<div style="color: #ff0000;">
This is the Heading
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using rich text area field? I tried and it works.Maybe you can explain specifically what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Froala editor for Rich Text Area.

Comment: Is this related to Salesforce?When you tag Remote Action , do you mean you are trying to save this HTML using Remote Action?

Comment: hmm... as I wrote, when I sending the data to the RemoteAction ... it is removing that. In the DebugLogs I saw the data just before saving and I see there is no font-family after it was saved.

Comment: What is the field type for value that you want to save into, is Rich Text Area?

Comment: Yes, Rich Text Area(131072).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this will help you.This is what I experiment it.If you can see it in debug log , I assume the value is successfully passed to the controller but it is not update to the database.So this is what I did, and I check the value is saved in the database.

```
List<Opportunity> lst =[Select Id, Rich_Text__c from Opportunity where Id='00690000002F4sD'];

Opportunity opp = lst[0];
String str='<div style=\'font-family: "Ravi Prakash"; color: #ff0000;\'>This is the Heading</div>';
opp.Rich_Text__c =str.escapeHtml4();

update opp;
```

Based on this, you might want to check [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm?search_text=String) and use relevant method at your string value. In this case I use escapeHtml4().

Comment: It saving as &lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&#39;color: #ff0000; font-family: &quot;Ravi Prakash&quot;, cursive;&#39;&gt;Creating Topics...!!&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;